# Magento 2, call external web service when order is placed

Tags: web-services, magento2

I've been digging around and I can't seem to find the answer to what I'm looking for at all.

I need to call an external web service when an order is placed in magento 2. I also need to use the order information in the call. I simply dont know what the right path is. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is late, but here is the solution that works for me, I have written observer for event `checkout_submit_all_after`.

Create file at path **[CompanyName]/[ModuleName]/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="push_orders_to_purchaser" instance="RLTSquare\Quote\Observer\PushOrdersToPurchaserApi" />
    </event>

</config>
```

Now in observer (**[CompanyName]/[ModuleName]/observer/PushOrdersToPurchaserApi.php**)

```
    <?php

    namespace RLTSquare\Quote\Observer;

    use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl;

    class PushOrdersToPurchaserApi implements ObserverInterface
    {
        const MOCK_API = 'https://yourwebsite.com/insertorders';

        protected $_request;
        protected $_webApiRequest;
        protected $_serviceOutputProcessor;
        protected $_zendClientFactory;


        public function __construct
        (
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
            \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $webApiRequest,
            \Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor $serviceOutputProcessor,
            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $zendClientFactory
        )
        {
            $this->_request = $request;
            $this->_webApiRequest = $webApiRequest;
            $this->_serviceOutputProcessor = $serviceOutputProcessor;
            $this->_zendClientFactory = $zendClientFactory;

        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order[] $orders
             */
            $orders = $observer->getOrders();

            $encodedData = null;
            if ($orders) {
                $data = $this->_serviceOutputProcessor->convertValue($orders, '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface[]');
                $payload = \Zend_Json::encode($data, true);

                $client = $this->_zendClientFactory->create();
                $client->setUri(self::MOCK_API);
                $client->setConfig(['maxredirects' => 0, 'timeout' => 30]);
                $client->setRawData($payload);
                $response = $client->request(\Zend_Http_Client::POST)->getBody();


   //play with response here...

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little over 4 years later... and this is literally exactly what I need to do.  I'm a new Magento dev and this has helped tremendously.  Thank you!